# ASP.NET и Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net

Стояла у меня VS 13 с update 2 (или 3, уже не вспомню). Я решил поставить себе Web Develop tools, но так понял, что для 13 студии они идут вместе с 4 update-ом. Я его скачал, установил. Вместе с ним встала MS Web Platform Installer, где напротив всех нужных для студии компонентов написано installed. Но в самой студии во вкладке C#/Web ничего нет. Гуглил: решение - переустановить студию, но это как-то слишком радикально, да и не хочется SSD зря гонять. Как можно это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего при первоначальной установке студии не были поставлены компоненты для web-разработкию

откройте Control Panel/Add Remove Programs, найдите там Visual Studio, нажмите Change, потом в визарде Modify и выберите там Microsoft Web Developer Tools.

Update 4 после этого скорее всего придется поставить заново.